# Is there any reason the code shouldn't be functioning correctly with the TRY function?

Tags: python

I'm working on a code that analyzes customers shopping for DVDs and CDs and the code seems to be debugged but still won't run properly.

I've tried debugging and even completely restarting the code:

```
try:
    #open file name disks.txt
    infile = open('disk.txt', 'r')

    #read first line of the file which is the customer name field and display.
    customer_name = customer_name.rstrip('\n')
    print(code, end='\t')

    #Read the spindles field. strip new line character and display
    spindles = infile.readline()
    spindles = int(spindles)
    print(format(spindles, '3.0f'), end='\t')

    #Check code and compute payment due.
    #increment appropriate counter
    if code == "C" or code == "c":
        payment_due = spindles * CW_RW_PRICE
        cd_customer_counter += 1
    elif code == "D" or code == "d":
        payment_due = spindles * DVD_RW_PRICE
        dvd_customers_counter += 1
    else:
        payment_due = 0
```

The code should just be letting me enter in the customer and the number of items they're purchasing to get the payment amount due. Instead, it's telling me the `try` function is invalid

Comment: You can't have a `try` without at least one corresponding `except` or `finally` clause.  What were you expecting a `try` by itself to even do?

Comment: `try` is not a function. Unless you put parenthesis after it, it's not a function. For example, you'd never write `try(1, 2, 3)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/) to a nice tutorial on how try-catch blocks work

Comment: Here on Stack Overflow we like to give complete answers. Just giving a link is not considered complete. Also keep in mind that links can and will become dead.